# ms access query returns inconsistent results each time

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access 2010 database that I am querying in SQL (as opposed to via the Design View screen), however the query keeps returning a different number of records each time I run it.  Mostly it returns 986 rows, but sometimes it returns just 985 rows (with the missing row never being the same missing row as the last time) and sometimes it even returns 984 rows or even 982 rows.

I have selectively removed parts of the SQL and run it, and I seem to get the inconsistent results when the SQL contains the SWITCH function:

```
SELECT 
  BU.vcrName AS [Business Unit], 
  Team.vcrName AS Team, 
  TmplHdr.vcrName AS Template, 
  Tmpl.intVersion AS Version,
  switch(Tmpl.dtmCreated is not null and Tmpl.dtmCompleted is null and Tmpl.dtmDeactivated is null, "In Development",
         Tmpl.dtmCompleted is not null and Tmpl.dtmAuthorised is null and Tmpl.dtmDeactivated is null, "Awaiting Authorisation",
         Tmpl.dtmAuthorised is not null and Tmpl.dtmDeactivated is null and Tmpl.intId in (select intId from qryLiveTemplates), "Live",
         Tmpl.dtmAuthorised is not null and Tmpl.dtmDeactivated is null and Tmpl.intId not in (select intId from qryLiveTemplates), "Inactive",
         Tmpl.dtmDeactivated is not null, "Deactivated",
     true, "unknown status") as Status,
  TmplHdr.intId as TemplateHeaderId
FROM 
  ((TblBusinessUnit AS BU INNER JOIN TblTeam AS Team ON BU.intId = Team.intBusUnitId) 
   INNER JOIN TblTemplateHeader AS TmplHdr ON Team.intId = TmplHdr.intTeamId) 
   INNER JOIN TblTemplate AS Tmpl ON TmplHdr.intId = Tmpl.intTemplateHeaderId
ORDER BY BU.vcrName asc, Team.vcrName asc, TmplHdr.vcrName asc, Tmpl.intVersion DESC;
```

Given that the underlying source data (held in tables inside that database) is not changing, has anyone got any suggestions as to why it's returning different results each time I run it?

Comment: _Something_ is changing, either the data, the query, or you are querying two different databases.  You say it's not the data changing but sometimes something obvious is overlooked.

Comment: AFAIK nothing is changing.  It's a standalone database (i.e. no links to any other data source) and the only window I have open on that database is the query one.

Comment: To rule out any "interference" from other apps, I have rebooted the machine and only opened MS Access and then run only that query, and I still get the indeterminate results.

Comment: So the `Status` field is inconsistent? Which part of it is inconsistent? Are there any Modules/Macros being ran on opening of Access or at any point prior to/after this is being ran? Are other people use it?

Comment: The number of records being returned is inconsistent.  I would have expected the same number of records to be returned every time I run the query (given that the query is not changing and neither is the data). There are no macros running on opening or after opening, and I'm the only one with access to that database at the moment (it's in development).